# Python Argparse with ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter and RawTextHelpFormatter

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse with Python 2.7
I would like to use `RawTextHelpFormatter` to get line feeds in the epilog
*and* `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` to get the defaults displayed in the default help.

For example, if the epilog part of ArgumentParser is:

```
 epilog="first line\n second line"
```

and there are arguments:

```py
group.add_argument(
    "-d",
    "--development",
    action="store_true",
    dest="build_dev",
    default="False",
    help="Build development code",
)
group.add_argument(
    "-p",
    "--production",
    action="store_true",
    dest="build_prod",
    default="False",
    help="Build production release",
)
```

The help output should be:

```
   -d, --development   Build development code (default: False)
   -p, --production    Build production release (default: False)
first line
second line
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: Simplest is to just include your own 'default' formatting to the help lines: `help="Build development code (default: %(default)s"`, and just use the `Raw` formatter.   Or you could define a new formatter subclass that inherits from both of the existing subclasses (that's developer approved).

Comment: @mkrieger1 I either use RawTextHelpFormatter and get the line breaks or I use ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter  and get the defaults.

Comment: @hpaulj - Thanks! That worked perfectly.  You can add a ) after the s and make it an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inserting your own default in the help works but is not ideal. This is because it is an unnecessary maintenance burden for the following reasons:

- every new argument will need that text added
- all that repetition clutters the code obscuring the details that matter
- future design changes such as no longer showing the defaults would require deleting that text from every argument
- advanced features such as making whether to show the defaults a user configurable option would be excluded by the hard-coding of the default text

Therefore, it is much better to take advantage of python's multiple inheritance to make a new formatter with the functionality of all the relevant supplied formatters, in this case RawTextHelpFormatter and ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, e.g. like this:

```py
import argparse


class UltimateHelpFormatter(
    argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter, argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
):
    pass


group = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    epilog="first line\n second line",
    formatter_class=UltimateHelpFormatter,
)
group.add_argument(
    "-d",
    "--development",
    action="store_true",
    dest="build_dev",
    default="False",
    help="Build development code",
)
group.add_argument(
    "-p",
    "--production",
    action="store_true",
    dest="build_prod",
    default="False",
    help="Build production release",
)
group.print_help()
```

The above gives this output:

```
usage: prog.py [-h] [-d] [-p]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -d, --development  Build development code (default: False)
  -p, --production   Build production release (default: False)

first line
 second line
```

Answer (score 2):

Inserting your own `default` in the help:

```
In [324]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter, 
     ...:    epilog="first line\n second line") 
     ...: group = parser.add_argument_group('test') 
     ...: group.add_argument( 
     ...:     "-d", 
     ...:     "--development", 
     ...:     action="store_true", 
     ...:     dest="build_dev", 
     ...:     default="False", 
     ...:     help="Build development code (default: %(default)s)", 
     ...:  ) 
     ...: group.add_argument( 
     ...:     "-p", 
     ...:     "--production", 
     ...:     action="store_true", 
     ...:     dest="build_prod", 
     ...:     default="False", 
     ...:     help="Build production release (default: %(default)s", 
     ...:  )                                                                                           
Out[324]: _StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['-p', '--production'], dest='build_prod', nargs=0, const=True, default='False', type=None, choices=None, help='Build production release (default: %(default)s', metavar=None)
In [325]: parser.print_help()                                                                          
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-d] [-p]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit

test:
  -d, --development  Build development code (default: False)
  -p, --production   Build production release (default: False

first line
 second line
```

Answer (score -2):

Use epilog argument

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
...     prog='PROG',
...     description='''this description
...         was indented weird
...             but that is okay''',
...     epilog='''
...             likewise for this epilog whose whitespace will
...         be cleaned up and whose words will be wrapped
...         across a couple lines''')
>>> parser.print_help()
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#description

Comment: I was using the epilog argument.  That is what I am trying to format

Comment: instead of adding newline you can print it on multiline like above